# Django Registration or or django auth?

Tags: django, django-registration

I am new to Django and trying to build a social networking site that requires these steps for new users:

Fill Registration forms -> Fill some profile forms -> Verify account from email -> Use

pip has installed Django 1.5.4.

My question is: For this Scenario, should I use [Django-registraion](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) or the native Django-auth or some other module? Which option would you recommend and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the level of customization you want to have.

A registration form could look a bit like repetitive task among different Django projects, and it is considering most of the registration processes require the same basic steps. However, for different projects you may need to extend or exclude certain steps.

This is an example of a view I use for registration:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if register_form.is_valid():
            data = register_form.data

            # create user
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=data.get('username'),
                email=data.get('email'),
                password=data.get('password'),
            )

            if user is not None:
                auth = authenticate(username=data.get('username'), password=data.get('password'))
                login(request, auth)

                messages.success(request, _('Your new user has been created.'))
                return redirect(reverse('home'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, _('Oops! Error.'))
    else:
        register_form = RegisterForm()

    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html')
```

This works for almost all my projects. `RegisterForm` has all the magic.

Comment: I'd prefer to do it using auth, mostly for education reason,  but just a bit worried of managing registration verification through email. How do you do that?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it. You can create a model that has a OneToOne field to User and another field that contains the verification key. In `register` view in my answer, create a new instance of your verification model and fire up an email to the user with a link to verify. Create a view and a URL to check the model for the key and do the rest. A different approach is to cache your key and avoid models/tables.

Answer (score 0):

django-allauth is a fairly complete solution. Even if you are not interested in the social login and integration features, it makes very easy for you to handle user registration, profile, email validation, etc.